# Custom Caption Bar Buttons Successful but

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

My code. Begged and borrowed.

```
unit uFrm_Details;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.Buttons;

const
  BTN_TOP = 10;

type
  TFFrm_Details = class(TForm)
    procedure FormResize(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FDownButton: TRect;
    FUpButton: TRect;
    FCloseButton: TRect;
    FCBMP, FDBMP, FUBMP: TBitmap;
    FYCaption, FXTtlBit, FYTtlBit: Integer;
    FHandle: TCanvasDC;
    procedure DrawTitleButton;
    procedure DrawFinalize;
    procedure FoldDown;
    procedure FoldUp;
    {Paint-related messages}
    procedure WMSetText(var Msg: TWMSetText); message WM_SETTEXT;
    procedure WMNCPaint(var Msg: TWMNCPaint); message WM_NCPAINT;
    procedure WMNCActivate(var Msg: TWMNCActivate); message WM_NCACTIVATE;
    {Mouse down-related messages}
    procedure WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest); message WM_NCHITTEST;
    procedure WMNCLButtonDown(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonDown); message WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN;
    procedure WMNCLButtonUp(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonUp); message WM_NCLBUTTONUP;

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

const
  htCloseBtn = htSizeLast + 100;
  htDropBtn =  htSizeLast + 101;
  htCloseUpBtn = htSizeLast + 102;

var
  FFrm_Details: TFFrm_Details;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses uFrm_Main;

{ TTitleBtnForm }

procedure TFFrm_Details.DrawFinalize;
begin
  with FCloseButton do
    Canvas.Draw(Left, Top, FCBMP);

  with FDownButton do
    Canvas.Draw(Left, Top, FDBMP);

  with FUpButton do
    Canvas.Draw(Left, Top, FUBMP);

  ReleaseDC(Self.Handle, FHandle);
  FCBMP.Free;
  FDBMP.Free;
  FUBMP.Free;
  FHandle:= 0;
end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.DrawTitleButton;
begin
  FXTtlBit:= GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSIZE); {Button Width}
  FYTtlBit:= GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSIZE); {Button Height}
  FYCaption:= GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION); {Caption Height}

  FCloseButton:= Bounds(Width - FXTtlBit - 5, BTN_TOP, FXTtlBit, FYTtlBit);
  FDownButton:= Bounds(Width - (2 * FXTtlBit) - 3, BTN_TOP, FXTtlBit, FYTtlBit);
  FUpButton:= Bounds(Width - (3 * FXTtlBit) - 1, BTN_TOP, FXTtlBit, FYTtlBit);

  Canvas.Handle := GetWindowDC(Self.Handle);
  FHandle:= Canvas.Handle;

  FCBMP:= TBitmap.Create;
  FDBMP:= TBitmap.Create;
  FUBMP:= TBitmap.Create;

end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.FoldDown;
begin
  if ClientHeight = 0 then
    ClientHeight:= 100;
end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.FoldUp;
begin
  if ClientHeight > 0 then
    ClientHeight:= 0;
end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  Perform(WM_NCACTIVATE, Word(Active), 0);
end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.WMNCActivate(var Msg: TWMNCActivate);
begin
  inherited;

  DrawTitleButton;

  with FFrm_Main.ImageList1 do
  begin
    if Msg.Active = True then
    begin
      GetBitmap(1, FCBMP);
      GetBitmap(5, FDBMP);
      GetBitmap(9, FUBMP);
    end
    else
    begin
      GetBitmap(0, FCBMP);
      GetBitmap(4, FDBMP);
      GetBitmap(8, FUBMP);
    end;
  end;

  DrawFinalize;

end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.WMNCHitTest(var Msg: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  inherited;

  {Check to see if the mouse was clicked in the area of the button}
  with Msg do
  begin
    if PtInRect(FCloseButton, Point(XPos - Left, YPos - Top)) then
    begin
      DrawTitleButton;

      with FFrm_Main.ImageList1 do
      begin
        GetBitmap(2, FCBMP);
        GetBitmap(5, FDBMP);
        GetBitmap(9, FUBMP);
      end;

      DrawFinalize;

      Result:= htCloseBtn;
    end;

    if PtInRect(FDownButton, Point(XPos - Left, YPos - Top)) then
    begin
      DrawTitleButton;

      with FFrm_Main.ImageList1 do
      begin
        GetBitmap(1, FCBMP);
        GetBitmap(6, FDBMP);
        GetBitmap(9, FUBMP);
      end;

      DrawFinalize;

      Result:= htDropBtn;
    end;

    if PtInRect(FUpButton, Point(XPos - Left, YPos - Top)) then
    begin
      DrawTitleButton;

      with FFrm_Main.ImageList1 do
      begin
        GetBitmap(1, FCBMP);
        GetBitmap(5, FDBMP);
        GetBitmap(10, FUBMP);
      end;

      DrawFinalize;

      Result:= htCloseUpBtn;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.WMNCLButtonDown(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonDown);
begin
  inherited;

  if (Msg.HitTest = htCloseBtn) then
  begin
    DrawTitleButton;

    with FFrm_Main.ImageList1 do
    begin
      GetBitmap(3, FCBMP);
      GetBitmap(5, FDBMP);
      GetBitmap(10, FUBMP);
    end;

    DrawFinalize;
  end;

  if (Msg.HitTest = htDropBtn) then
  begin
    DrawTitleButton;

    with FFrm_Main.ImageList1 do
    begin
      GetBitmap(1, FCBMP);
      GetBitmap(7, FDBMP);
      GetBitmap(10, FUBMP);
    end;

    DrawFinalize;
  end;

  if (Msg.HitTest = htCloseUpBtn) then
  begin
    DrawTitleButton;

    with FFrm_Main.ImageList1 do
    begin
      GetBitmap(1, FCBMP);
      GetBitmap(5, FDBMP);
      GetBitmap(11, FUBMP);
    end;

    DrawFinalize;
  end;

end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.WMNCLButtonUp(var Msg: TWMNCLButtonUp);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Msg.HitTest = htCloseBtn) then
    Hide;

  if (Msg.HitTest = htDropBtn) then
    FoldDown;

  if (Msg.HitTest = htCloseUpBtn) then
    FoldUp;
end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.WMNCPaint(var Msg: TWMNCPaint);
begin
  inherited;
  DrawTitleButton;

  with FFrm_Main.ImageList1 do
  begin
    GetBitmap(1, FCBMP);
    GetBitmap(5, FDBMP);
    GetBitmap(9, FUBMP);
  end;

  DrawFinalize;

end;

procedure TFFrm_Details.WMSetText(var Msg: TWMSetText);
begin
  inherited;
  DrawTitleButton;

  with FFrm_Main.ImageList1 do
  begin
    GetBitmap(1, FCBMP);
    GetBitmap(5, FDBMP);
    GetBitmap(9, FUBMP);
  end;

  DrawFinalize;
end;

end.
```

All works as expected so far. The code is far from perfect and I will tweak it for better performance etc.
I drop another component onto the client area and run the program.
Nothing is visible in the client area of the form whatsoever.
This has me stumped.

If I create each component I need in the client area in the 'OnCreate' event and destroy those components in the 'OnDestroy event I see what I expected to see after I dropped the components on the client area initially.

My question.

Why is this so? What have I missed in the winapi documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is to overlook how 'canvas' works, rather than anything related with the api.

```
procedure TFFrm_Details.DrawTitleButton;
begin
  ...
  Canvas.Handle := GetWindowDC(Self.Handle);
  FHandle:= Canvas.Handle;
  ...
end;
```

Here you retrieve a window DC and assign it to canvas handle. The 'FHandle' field is one of the things you'll optimize out.

```
procedure TFFrm_Details.DrawFinalize;
begin
  ...
  ReleaseDC(Self.Handle, FHandle);
  FCBMP.Free;
  FDBMP.Free;
  FUBMP.Free;
  FHandle:= 0;
end;
```

And here you're leaving the canvas in an indeterminate state. As far as it knows, it has a valid device context. But you pull that from under it's feet. To correct, set the canvas handle to 0.

```
  ...
  Canvas.Handle := 0;
  ReleaseDC(Self.Handle, FHandle);
  ...
```

The problem manifests itself while the form is streaming. That's why if you create the controls at run-time it works.

In particular, `TCustomForm.ReadState` checks to see if the font size is different than that of the design time to scale the controls appropriately. The invalid device context handle causes the canvas to fail at getting the font height: the api call `GetTextExtentPoint32` fails which the VCL does not check the return of, and the canvas reports a text height of '0'. The controls are appropriately scaled to width/height 0, effectively rendering them invisible.

Comment: Thank-you very much.
That is obvious now you have pointed my failings out!
It looked an interesting piece of code and wanted to try it out and was pleased with the result with the caption buttons but couldn't figure out why I couldn't see the components I placed on the client area.
Thanks again.